# use of request manager design pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have observed in lot many C# example where in following pattern is being followed but i am not sure how this will going to help us in long run

Typical approach i have seen is

1. create a interface
2. implement interface
3. create a manager
4. call manager

it would be really nice if anyone can tell me how this approach will going to help in real world senario

interface `IRestService` for various web requests

```
public interface IRestService
    {
        Task<List<TodoItem>> RefreshDataAsync ();

        Task SaveTodoItemAsync (TodoItem item, bool isNewItem);

        Task DeleteTodoItemAsync (string id);
    }
```

Code that implements `IRestService` interface

```
public class RestService : IRestService
{
    HttpClient client;

    public List<TodoItem> Items { get; private set; }

    public RestService ()
    {
        var authData = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Constants.Username, Constants.Password);
        var authHeaderValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authData));

        client = new HttpClient ();
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authHeaderValue);
    }

    public async Task<List<TodoItem>> RefreshDataAsync ()
    {


    }

    public async Task SaveTodoItemAsync (TodoItem item, bool isNewItem = false)
    {

    }

    public async Task DeleteTodoItemAsync (string id)
    {

    }
}
```

`Manager` that calls the implemented methods

```
public class TodoItemManager
{
    IRestService restService;

    public TodoItemManager (IRestService service)
    {
        restService = service;
    }

    public Task<List<TodoItem>> GetTasksAsync ()
    {
        return restService.RefreshDataAsync (); 
    }

    public Task SaveTaskAsync (TodoItem item, bool isNewItem = false)
    {
        return restService.SaveTodoItemAsync (item, isNewItem);
    }

    public Task DeleteTaskAsync (TodoItem item)
    {
        return restService.DeleteTodoItemAsync (item.ID);
    }
}
```

to execute request

```
TodoManager = new TodoItemManager (new RestService ()); 
TodoManager.GetTasksAsync ();
```

few questions are running in my mind

1. why we need a manager why can not we just use `RestService`
2. if some day i need to develop one module to fetch contact related data from server then do i need to add methods in `IRestServie` to `addContact()` , `deleteContact()` , `getContact()`

Comment: Relevant: [Where and how is the term used WRAPPER in programming, what does it help to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293752/where-and-how-is-the-term-used-wrapper-in-programming-what-does-it-help-to-do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why we need a manager?

The manager represents the business logic that surrounds calling a rest service. Your example was a little to simple to see why a manager can be useful.  Consider the use case where you need to deal with multiple REST services.  But this is where you can handle pre-validation of data, do a follow-on call if `addContact` succeeds or fails, etc.

### Why not use `RestService` Directly?

**Testing.**  It makes testing your business logic (manager) separately from your rest service.

**Versioning.**  It makes replacing the implementation of your `RestService` easier when the implementation needs to change due to versioning constraints.

**Containment.**  The primary reason is to contain your business logic separately from your presentation logic.  It also minimizes the impact if the new version of a `RestService` causes some extra steps that you have to maintain in code.  By keeping one interface you have control over the same (your manager) you can contain the changes required by a change in an interface you don't really have control over (rest service).

### Fetching new data from a new service

`IRestService` is a bad name for this reason.  You would have separate interfaces for each REST service you needed to contact.  For example, you would have a `ITodoRestService` and a `IContactRestService` or something like that.  If your `TodoManager` needed to use both (i.e. associating todo items with a contact), it would have a reference to both.  Which then leads you back to why we need a manager in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

An interface is meant to hide the details of concrete classes implementing them. This means you can type-hint on the interface and not worry about what concrete object is actually performing the methods.

A “REST service” seems to be a poor candidate for an interface to me, as REST itself *is an implementation detail*. Instead, there should probably be a “todo list” interface, and then implementations: a class that loads a todo list from a REST service, a class that loads a todo list from the file system, and so on.

If you took this approach, and then depended on the interface, it removes the need for a manager in my opinion, as you’ll have dependency injection wired up somewhere that says, “When I request an instance of `ITodoList`, give me an instance of `RestBasedTodoList`”.

Answer (score 0):

Your naming doesn't seem quite right.

`IRestService` is the interface of some service which you are calling

your `RestService`, is actually a client for that service. so call it one

```
RestServiceClient : IRestService
```

then your `Manager` is some application which uses the service to do stuff. Normally this will require more than a single service and it will be a `Controller`, or a `ViewModel` or something

```
public class TodoItemController
{
    IRestService client;
    IAnotherService client2;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var x = client.DoThing();
        client2.DoSomethingElse(x/2);
        MessageBox("I DID IT!");
    }
}
```

Maybe, you just have many simple cases where the logic is just passed down. In those cases, yes I think you can safely skip the `Manager` class. But perhaps you are putting the logic somewhere else and really you need to move it to the correct layer?